# Is there a standard name / templated prototype for "congruent hash" vs "identity hash"?

Tags: c++, hash, std, naming, unordered-map

I have a templated class `Foo` that can do identity comparisons (via `==`), but has a function `Foo::sameStructureAs(Foo const & other)` for more of a "value" vs. "pointer" notion of equality.

I'd like to make an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) which overrides the hash function and the equality predicate.  They default to `std::equal_to<Key>` and `std::hash<Key>`...which I provide for my type, based on identity.  But I need them to be comparing on the basis of my `sameStructureAs`.

Since Foo is a template, I do something like this:

```
template <class> struct same_structure_as;

template <class> struct hash_structure;

template <class T>
struct hash_structure<Foo<T>>
{
    size_t operator() (Foo<T> const & value) const
    {
        // whatever...
    }
};

template <class T>
struct same_structure_as<Foo<T>>
{
    bool operator() (Foo<T> const & left, Foo<T> const & right) const
    {
        // whatever...
    }
};
```

Which seems like I'm following roughly the strategy of the classes in `std::` for this purpose, and creating something general.  So does that look right?

Secondly: Is there any precedent for the naming of this or a prototype already existing in std::?  I've thought about words like `isomorphic` or `congruent`.  It seems like something that would come up often in designing classes when you have more than one idea of what it means to be "equal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at a type through this "different" notion of comparison or equality, ask if what you really need is *another type*.  Perhaps there is some kind of cast or coercion you would apply to the underlying data so that its new notion of equality/assignment/comparison fits this test you are designing.

That way you can properly implement the std:: functions for that type... and use it in collections without having to pass in these extra predicates.  So perhaps call the type with pointer-equality semantics `FooRef` and the one with value semantics `Foo`.

If for some reason you can't do this...then looking at the names one wants to parallel:

- `std::equal_to<Key>`
- `std::hash<Key>`

Keeping the `equal_to` and `hash` in there is probably the closest to "standard" one will accomplish.  So rather than introducing new terms like `congruence` or `isometric`,call out  exactly what is equal or getting hashed...and use the above as suffixes:

- `std::content_equal_to<Key>`
- `std::content_hash<Key>`

If it's the "structure" of something being compared you can apply that with `structure_equal_to` and `structure_hash`.  Only caveat being that "struct"/"structure" has meaning in C++, so it may lead a reader to think it's comparing type_info or something like that.